# Date formatter for date @"2013-04-19T05:29:59 05:30"

Tags: objective-c

i have tried formatting above date through @"YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'+05:30'"

but getting wrong date(2012-04-18 23:59:59 +0000) can anyone help i have not found this type of format any where

Comment: check https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html

Answer (score 0):

The usual response is to use the `strftime` function/method, but since you are not specifying any platform or framework this is the best answer you can get; to search for a `strftime` function in your framework of choice.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting it correct value.but in the GMT format.That is what you give input is +5:30 in time and the value you have in return is in GMT format see the answer has +0000 at end shows it is GMT format.To check add the result with 5:30 you will have the right value that you provided. Use `NSDateFormatter` to get it the correct format of date

what you are missing here is a space between ss and 05:30 
the correct format is

```
@"YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss '05:30'"
```

Use this to get the correct output

```
   NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss '05:30'"];
    NSDate *dateObj= [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2013-04-19T05:29:59 05:30"];
    NSLog(@"%@",dateObj);
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE MMMM d, YYYY"];
    NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateObj]);
```

Comment: thanks Lithu but can you check it for 2013-04-19T05:29:59+05:30   i have tried but din get right date

Comment: NSDate shows with the timezone, and you are 0530 hrs ahead of GMT, so you get time `2013-04-18 23:59:59 +0000`

Comment: @Abhishek : yeah you can check it but make sure the format and the entered time look alike in representation for this format.Note space also count

Comment: @Abhishek: For  this format in comment use @"YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'+05:30'"